# How to create a custom character in Turbo C++

Tags: c++, console, dos, character

I have come up to a point in C++ where I need a custom character. I'll try to explain what I mean to say: As you guys already know the characters in text mode are the patterns of dots, like the 'A' being as:

```
0000001000000
0000010100000
0000100010000
0001000001000
0001000001000
0001111111000
0001000001000
0001000001000
0001000001000
```

...where the 1's represent the active dot and 0's inactive. I want to know how do I create such a character by myself this way. I have been told that there is a way (without going through a huge mess), but I haven't been thoroughly guided. I hope I'll get help here. thanks.

Comment: This reminds me of the good ol Z80 days back in '89... `PEEK` and `POKE`, good times... By the way, it's 2011.

Comment: thank you jonathan wood for editing the body.

Comment: To answer Jonathan's answer in his deleted reply, Turbo C++ has only one platform: DOS.

Comment: btw sir here is the thing i am currently working on http://adf.ly/2BrNy  i want the equal (=) sign to be a little more wider like the complete block below it, i think it will look more appropriate. and that is why i need to make a custom character i am working in text mode. regards

Comment: @Mohammad - you might be working in text mode (although I seriously doubt it), but noone else does. Whom are you writing it for?

Comment: sir i can guarantee you that im working in text mode :) lol, and im working for no one i just wondered how they made the visualizations in winamp or other media players, so i decided to do it in text mode (becuase graphics mode doesnot work under my version of windows, i'd like to get help about that too ;) ) so i did this thing. its working fine but i just wanna make it look better

Comment: Pseudographic characters maybe? See my second answer.

Comment: Suddenly I feel so young. What is text mode and what has this to do with C++?

Comment: pseudo chars are just another chars, i want my own char ;)

Comment: Your char will have to take place of an existing one. There are only 255 different byte values out there; text mode is Unicode-unfriendly. So pick your victim...

Comment: yea so how do i pick that victim and replace it with something else?

Comment: but my problem has yet not been resolved

Comment: and yea the pseudo char has quite helped but i really wanna learn how to make my own characters

Comment: Which version of windows are you using?

Comment: AFAIK, The dos window in windows 7 is not able to run programs which use custom characters. It is not a real dos window. If you want a real dos window in windows 7, you have to install [dosbox](http://www.dosbox.com/). There are youtube videos how to install and use turbo c++ inside dosbox. If you use dosbox, you can really create custom characters in tc++.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're targeting DOS in text mode - read up on interrupt 10h, AH 11h. It lets you load user-defined characters into the character generator memory. See here: http://webpages.charter.net/danrollins/techhelp/0151.HTM

I don't think Turbo C has a wrapper function for that particual call. For invoking interrupts directly, use the int86() function.

Comment: i think that will be helpful :) i think i should learn about calling interrupts first :)

Comment: If you just want a double horizontal line, this is an overkill. See my other answer.

Comment: Note: the int 10h trick will only work in true text mode in proper DOS. Console window on Windows (or Linux) is not text mode. It just pretends, to a degree.

Answer (score 2):

This is dealing with the video adapter text mode memory, BIOS int 10h calls, etc. So 1990's... Most modern operating systems don't work in text mode, and use TrueType fonts (even for "console" applications that emulate text mode).

Comment: whoa sir that flew jusy above my head :) is there not a simple way i can do the thing? i am working in console app and text mode using rad studio.

Comment: @Mohammad - no, there's no simple way you can do that. Console app is not in text mode in the sense you need. It is still in graphics mode, and uses fonts provided by the OS/windows manager to draw the text. You can force users to use a custom font with your application, but it's a setting on the user's console, or something you can do with a Windows API call, having a TTF file ready to be loaded.

Comment: sir litlleadv i think you are the man im looking for :) i believe only u have understood what i wanted to say here (about the representation of bits as pixels)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a double horizontal line character that takes the whole block, so that a line runs uninterrupted, the pseudographic character 0xCD (═) might help.

It depends on the current codepage, but most national codepages (including the Cyrillic 866) leave the pseudographic characters intact.

Just output a row of 0xCDs, see how it looks.

```
for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    putchar(0xcd);
```